# Limit involving greatest integer function

Tags: limits

I can't work out this. The answer given is $1$, though I am getting infinity.

Please help me out

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^n+nx^{n-1}+1}{[x]}=?$$

Comment: Is the question to find n when given that the limit approaches 1? Because the limit depends on what n is.